# Access next & prev array inside array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [question] => first question
            [answer] => first answer
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [question] => second question
            [answer] => second answer
        )
)
```

I want to have a "Previous" and "Next" button on the page, and when we click one or the other, the previous or next array is selected so I can echo out items on the page.

So for example if the page loads and Array[0] is printed out by default, clicking next should then print out Array[1].

Comment: Do you mean to use php along with html and javascript? If so share your tried code with html

Comment: Yes, I can manage that part, for now just need to learn how to do this in PHP

Comment: If you want to do this without reloading the page, you could use `json_encode()` to turn the PHP array into a JavaScript array.

Comment: Save the current array index in a variable. When the user goes to the next or previous item, increment or decrement they array index, and display the values from that element.

Comment: declare variable `$currentIndex=0`. And Increase this variable upon `Next` and decrease upon `Previous`. And then use this `$currentIndex` to get values out of array like `$arr[$currentIndex]`

Comment: If you do this in PHP, that will need to be a session variable so it persists between calls to the server.

Comment: On page load, I'm initializing $_SESSION['counter'] = 0. Then, when we click "Next" button, I'm incrementing it, like $_SESSION['counter']++. But the problem is, how do I prevent the counter from going back to 0 each time the page loads? Since it's initialized at top of the file.

Comment: Check if `$_SESSION['counter']` is already set, before you initialize it with 0.

Comment: @Barmar question about your comment, the json_encode() comment. Atleast on my local server, the PHP array cycles  through items in the array so quickly when I push "next" or "previous", that it doesn't even seem like the page is refreshing at all to the user. So my question is, is there any other benefit to moving the array to JS, other than improving the UX for the user (which in my case doesn't seem to even apply since the PHP is working so fast already?)

Comment: Usually refreshing is noticeably slower than doing it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP sessions to store the current index ID of the array is one solution, or you could simply use a query string parameter too?

This would looks something like this in PHP:

```php
$dataSet = [
    [],
    [],
];

$record = (!empty($_GET['recordId']) ? $_GET['recordId'] : 0);

if (!isset($dataSet[$record])) {
    echo 'Record not found';
    exit;
}

print_r($dataSet[$record]);

if ($record > 0) {
    echo '<a href="?recordId=' . $record-1 . '">Previous</a>';
}

if (count($dataSet) < $record+1) {
    echo '<a href="?recordId=' . $record+1 . '">Next</a>';
}
```